# Файл этого типа может нанести вред компьютеру Chrome 73

Tags: google-chrome, ruby, selenium

Пытаюсь через Selenium на Ruby управлять браузером Chrome v.73.
При скачивании файлов постоянно вылетает предупреждение "Файл этого типа может нанести вред компьютеру".

Никакие советы по отключению safebrowsing не помогают.
Пробовал запуск с --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection, safebrowsing.enabled = false.

Как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Может он прав? :) и то что вы скачивание действительно `может нанести вред компьютеру`

Comment: Используйте Firefox))))